# Node GET request finishing before Alexa Skill is run.

Tags: node.js, get

I'm writing an Alexa Skill that makes an API call to Google Calendar, but my GET request is not working.

```
var request = require('request');
console.log("Before requests");

request(getUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);  
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);  
    console.log('body:', body);  
});
```

I'm using `request` to make the http call and this code is literally just copied from the [github page](https://github.com/request/request), but nothing is logged to the console, so I'm not sure how to debug what's going wrong. Using other methods like `http.get(options, callback)` have yielded the same results - any console.log() in the callback does not get executed. Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!

--

A few other things - my `console.log("Before requests");` shows up, and my getUrl may not have the correct api key to make the request, but it should still be returning an error instead of not working at all.

This code is running through an Amazon Lambda Function (AWS) and I'm seeing the logs through AWS Cloudwatch. It appears that if I run my code in my terminal `node index.js` the request goes through just fine.

--

`console.log(request);` outputs:

```
jar: [Function],
      [ 'accept',
        'accept-charset',
        'accept-encoding',
        'accept-language',
        'accept-ranges',
        'cache-control',
        'content-encoding',
        'content-language',
        'content-location',
        'content-md5',
        'content-range',
        'content-type',
        'connection',
        'date',
        'expect',
        'max-forwards',
        'pragma',
        'referer',
        'te',
        'user-agent',
        'via' ],
     defaultProxyHeaderExclusiveList: [ 'proxy-authorization' ] },
  initParams: [Function: initParams],
  debug: [Getter/Setter]
```

EDIT:

All i had to do was wrap my request in a promise, which now seems obvious to me in hindsight. 
It was something like so:

```
var request = require('request');
console.log("Before requests");

return new Promise((res,rej) => {

    // getUrl is the the url and returns the data when entered into my browser            
    request(getUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        resolve(body);
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't used `request` before - but out of curiosity, what happens if you `console.log(request)`? (before invoking it, of course)

Comment: could it be the url being passed in?

Comment: what is the url?

Comment: Is your 'Before requests' console.log appearing?

Comment: @skwidbreth - this is updated in the question.

Comment: @iamjhu and chenkeh the URL is a simple google api request - even if it doesn't work it should still return a 403 response, but i'm not getting anything.

Comment: @Tom, yes. this is appear as are console.logs after the request is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - after making my API call I was moving straight to `this.emit(:tell, ".....");` effectively finishing the program before allowing the API response to come back. I had to wrap my API call in a promise to make sure that it ran before telling Alexa to respond.

Comment: I edited my question to show the request being wrapped in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work fine?

```
var options = {
    url: $link, //paste your link here
    method: 'GET'//or POST or whatever you want
};
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I believe it's an issue with putting my code in AWS lambda and running it from the Amazon Developer console, but I'm not sure why this would be a problem.